Question about axioms of addition
I am reading Rudin's Analysis (baby rudin). After covering axioms of addition, he proves (1.14) that if $x+y = x + z$ then $y = z$ (cancellation law). I think converse is also true here. If $y = z$, then $x + y = x + z$, though he doesn't say so. Here is my little proof. Suppose $y = z$.
I am referring to the axioms used from the book (page 5) on the right side
$$ \therefore 0 + y = 0 + z \;\;(A4)$$
$$ \therefore ((-x) + x) + y = ((-x) + x) + z \;\;(A5) $$
$$ \therefore (-x) + (x + y) = (-x) + (x + z)  \;\;(A3) $$
And here we can use the cancellation law proven by Rudin (1.14 a) and finally state that
$$ x + y = x + z $$
So, this proves the converse of the cancellation law for the addition. Is this correct ?

If $y=z$, then $x+y=x+z$, since $x+y$ is the same thing as $x+z$. What else is there to say about it? More generally, if $y$ and $z$ belong to the domain of a function $f$ and if $y=z$, then $f(y)=f(z)$. There is nothing to prove here.

Not that it's wrong, but actually, this just follows from addition being a binary operation. If we denote the field by $F$ then addition is a function $A:F\times F\to F$ which satisfies the required axioms. For simplicity, we denote $A(x,y)=x+y$, this is just a notation. Now, if $y=z$ then $(x,y)=(x,z)$, and since $A$ is a function, this obviously implies $A(x,y)=A(x,z)$.

Mark, yes using definition of addition as a function really drove home the point for me.
